# Custom Map Annotation is blurry

Tags: swift, mapkitannotation, sketch-3

Hi I have created a custom annotation in Sketch 3 and when I scale it down to fit into the map view it becomes blurry. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to set the filtering Mode of your Node texture to `.Nearest`

```
 let nodeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "node")
 nodeTexture.filteringMode = .Nearest
 node = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTexture)
```

Comment: SKTexture and SKSpriteNode do not appear for me.  Do I need to import any frameworks?

Comment: Completly forgot that, you need to work with spritekit

Comment: I wasn't able to get what I what from your code , but I decided to go on www.makeappicon.com and I was able to use the scaled down icon that it made for the Apple Watch and now the image quality is very good. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I was having trouble with this too. Maybe this might help other people though, as you seem to have found a suitable solution.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseId = "id"
    var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if anView == nil {
        anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        anView!.canShowCallout = true
    }
    else {
        anView!.annotation = annotation
    }

    anView!.image = yourFullSizeImage
    anView!.frame.size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50) //Resize frame AFTER setting image, for me resizing frame first did not work

    return anView
}
```

Comment: Yeah I hade to use makeappicon.com to scale down my image. That was the only way I could do it